# uninstall unused Microsoft Office 365 programs to save space

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

I have a new Asus tablet running windows 10 and I want to uninstall parts of it like Access, OneNote, Publisher, that I will NEVER use on this device.
I have only 32GB of harddrive and with windows updates getting more and more I will have to trash my little computer within a month :(

Comment: This is a duplicate of several existing posts already. Including this one: https://superuser.com/questions/988002/office-2016-how-to-remove-individual-apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office 2016 - How to remove individual apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/988002/office-2016-how-to-remove-individual-apps)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I believe: Office 365 is different from traditional local MS Office, since 365 is web-based.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If it were web based, it wouldn't be taking up any space on the device, would it?

Comment: Not true: there's a client-side and a server-side portion. Note the rather involved uninstallation below for the client-side portion!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to uninstall individual parts of Office365. Which is really stupid and annoying, but there it is.

Answer (score -1):

First, the easy way: [There is a Microsoft *FixIt* tool to uninstall MS Office 365. Download tool from this link and run it.](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall)

Second, to satisfy the do-it-yourself crowd... well, it's a bit long:

Uninstall the main application as any other installed program:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and in the edit box type *prog*.
- Select *Add or remove programs*.
- Select *Office suite* and select *Uninstall*.
- To free up more space, you can remove the installer applications:

  - Open an elevated command prompt by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>, typing *cmd*, and pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> simultaneously. Then type the following three commands, and keep that CMD prompt open for later use:

> schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office 15 Subscription Heartbeat"
>
> schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Automatic Update"
>
> schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Subscription Maintenance"

- Now open Task Manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> simultaneously and kill any of the following processes on the *Details* tab that are running:

  - officeclicktorun.exe
  - appvshnotify.exe
  - firstrun.exe
  - setup*.exe
  - In the elevated CMD dialog, type:

> sc delete Clicktorunsvc

- Open Windows Explorer by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and delete any of the following, if present:

  - *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15* folder
  - *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ClickToRun* folder
  - *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Office\FFPackageLocker* file

[You can also delete Registry keys and Start Menu shortcuts, though that would not save much space.](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln265936/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-office-365-from-your-dell-pc?lang=en)

It does seem that MS made uninstallation obnoxious... they'd rather users buy into their software.