# Still possible to deploy Office 2016 using ODT in 2020?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016, office-deployment-tool

### TLDR;

I'm looking for a method for installing Office 2016 Pro Plus VL using ODT in 2020.

---

My workplace just updated all employee computers to Windows 10, but a few of them have to be reverted back to Windows 7 due to exotic legacy software. Office 2019 no longer supports Windows 7, so I would like to install Office 2016 for these computers. However I am not sure whether the current Office Deployment Tool still supports download and install of Office 2016. Specifically, I'm not sure which product ID corresponds to Office 2016 Pro Plus VL edition, for which my company has license keys.

So can I use ODT for this install? If so, do I have to use an older version of ODT, or am I fine with the newest ODT and just need a working configuration XML? Does anyone have a copy of those files?

---

#### Edit:

Using `ID="O365ProPlusRetail"` does not work. ODT will try and fail to install Office 2019. Also I am looking for VL edition, not retail edition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office 2016 - How to remove individual apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/988002/office-2016-how-to-remove-individual-apps)

Comment: While not applicable to your question, Windows 7 compatibility mode didn't work for the legacy software?

Comment: @Ramhound it does not. Using ID="O365ProPlusRetail" will attempt (and fail) to install the latest version (2019).

Comment: In addition I am looking for VL edition, not retail edition. For 2019 I know the product id is `ProPlus2019Volume`, but I do not know whether the equivalent exists for 2016.

Comment: @JW0914 I think they tried that. Of course I don't want them to carry on with Windows 7 either, but I don't make the final call.

Comment: Here is the thing I know it works.  [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026267/office-office-2016-deployment-tool) redirects you the same tool.   [This](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts) use to be the solution before Microsoft offered the same tool online.   The thing is the method hasn’t changed.  The office installer uses the XML file has an input.  While the tool to configure the xml might change that functionality to customize the installer hasn’t been retired

Comment: You should be using [ProPlusVolume](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/367938d8-9210-4c8f-aa5e-c8de41c0a7ca/odt-2016-invalid-product-proplusvolume-specified) if it doesn’t work someone offered up a version of the tool that should work.  All links to the tool from Microsoft redirect to the current version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think your needs could be achieved.

As Office ProPlus 2016 belongs to Office with MSI technology, but ODT (Office Deployment Tool) is apply to Office with C2R technology, such as Microsoft 365, Office 2019, the retail versions of Office 2013 and Office 2016.

There is no Product ID for Office ProPlus 2016 in "[List of Product IDs which are supported by the Office Deployment Tool for Click-to-Run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/installation/product-ids-supported-office-deployment-click-to-run)".

To deploy volume licensed Office 2016 and 2013, we could use OCT (Office Customization Tool) to customize MSI-based Office.

More detailed information, please checkout "[Customize installations of Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/ee460874(v=office.15))".

Comment: Office 2016 was also installed with C2R

Comment: Is there a place to obtain the 2016 VL media itself? OCT does not appear to provide a method for download as compared to the ODT. Specifying `ProPlus2016Volume` in ODT yields an `Invalid product` messages when doing the configure.

Comment: For volume licensed Office 2016, we need to download installation package from VLSC. But from volume licensed Office 2019, we can run ODT to download the package from CDN.

Answer (score 0):

The Office Deployment Tool treats any product ID without a version specifier as Office 2016, so `ID="ProPlusVolume"` should be what you want, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).